# Add a temporary claim From Account Controller Login Method

Tags: identityserver4

Using Identity Server Aspnet Identity Quickstart [Link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity), with EntityFramework for Persistent Storage.

I added a dropdown list to login page along with username and password fields. The user is supposed to select a value from dropdown list while logging into the Identityserver.

How can I add the selected value of the dropdown list as a claim for that particular session and send it back to clients along with requested claims?

My clients are MVC application which communicates with Identity Server using Hybrid Flow.

IdentityServer v2.0.2
MVC Client : AspNet Core 2.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Store the value in the signin cookie when calling SignInAsync
- Return the value as a claim in the `IProfileService`